# Change spellcheck language in my Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to write a Chrome extension that can switch the spellcheck language. I've searched through the Chrome API's and found the ChromeSetting object in the [Types](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/types.html) interface. However, I can't find any information on how to use it - e.g. what are the options for the "details" object?

Am I heading down the right path here? If so, does nayone have some examples or extra info that will help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, while `chrome.types` exists, you can't do anything with it.

We can run this code to see:

```
var c = chrome.types;
alert( Object.keys( c ).join(", ") );
```

Results:

```
[null]
```

This is despite the docs you linked to stating there are some methods available. My guess is it will be completed "someday" when Goog gets around to it.